# Pesquisa no DataFrames

Tags: python

```
DF-A                            DF-B 
col1    col2                    col1    col2
1   Teste1                       1      Teste1
2   Cidadania                    2      Cidadania   
3   Sol                          3      Lua
4   Moto                         4      Moto
5   Bike                         5      Bicicleta

                                
        DF-C        
            col1    col2        col3        
            1      Teste1       SIM     
            2      Cidadania    SIM     
            3      Sol          NÃO     
            4      Moto         SIM     
            5      Bike         NÃO
```

Como pesquisar no `DF-A` se o conteúdo da col2 existe no `DF-B` na col2. Se existir Mover a mensagem SIM, senão mover NÃO na col3 do `DF-C`.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solução atende perfeitamente para dataframes pequenos.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5], "col2": ["Teste1", "Cidadania", "Sol", "Moto", "Bike"]})

>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5], "col2": ["Teste1", "Cidadania", "Lua", "Moto", "Bicicleta"]})
```

```
>>> df_c = df_a.assign(col3=df_a.apply(lambda x: "SIM" if x["col2"] in df_b["col2"].tolist() else "NAO", axis=1))

>>> df_c
   col1       col2 col3
0     1     Teste1  SIM
1     2  Cidadania  SIM
2     3        Sol  NAO
3     4       Moto  SIM
4     5       Bike  NAO
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo. O que há de errado na resposta. Indique como posso melhorá-la.